# Does using higher isolation level decreases the probability of having deadlocks?

Tags: mysql, deadlock, isolation-level

So I am trying to learn MySQL and I came across the isolation levels (`SERIALIZED, REPEATABLE READ, READ COMMITED, READ UNCOMMITED`)

I believe my question is quite simple, but I did not find any information in the web so here it goes:

If I change the default `REPEATABLE READ` to `SERIALIZED` or even from `READ UNCOMMITED` to another higher level of isolation does I have less probabilities of having deadlock problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The possibility of deadlocks is not affected by isolation level. Isolation level changes the behavior of read operations, but deadlock occurs due to write operations. However, isolation level sets fewer locks, hence it can help you to avoid certain lock types (e.g. gap locking).

These tips to avoid dead_lock are very helpful https://www.percona.com/community-blog/2018/09/24/minimize-mysql-deadlocks-3-steps/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, deadlocks between `SELECT` operations on the one hand and `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on the other hand will be less likely if you use the more permissive `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level for your `SELECT` operations.

If it's OK for your `SELECT` operations not to get the results of concurrent changes to your tables, use that.